# Detect SRSI crossing number on tradingview and pinescript

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I want to get SRSI junction. I can receive SRSI crossing event in tradingview but I can't get junction.

For example:
[image: srsi crossing nubmers]

I want to get these numbers and crossing status. 85:short, 20:long: 90:short something like that. Is this possible on tradingview or any other platform like metatrader etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crossover()` and `crossunder()` functions for that.

> **crossover()**
>
> The `x`-series is defined as having crossed over
>   `y`-series if the value of `x` is greater than the value of `y` and
>   the value of `x` was less than the value of `y` on the bar immediately
>   preceding the current bar.
>
> **crossunder()**
>
> The `x`-series is defined as having crossed under
>   `y`-series if the value of `x` is less than the value of `y` and the
>   value of `x` was greater than the value of `y` on the bar immediately
>   preceding the current bar.

Then you can combine these with simple logic operations.

```
short = (line1 > 85) and (crossunder(line1, line2))
long = (line1 < 20) and (crossover(line1, line2))
```

Comment: Thanks I will look.